# Using mysql types in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mysqljs

I have a nodejs typescript project that requires the use of mysqljs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), I've imported the DefinitelyTyped package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mysql) and included them in my tsconfig file

tsconfig.json

> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       "noImplicitAny": false,
>       "module": "commonjs",
>       "noEmitOnError": true,
>       "removeComments": false,
>       "sourceMap": true,
>       "target": "es6"
>     },
>     "exclude": [
>       "node_modules"
>     ],
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "node_modules/@types",
>       "Scripts/typings/node"
>     ],
>     "types": [
>       "mysql",
>       "node"
>     ]
>   }

I can correctly use the mysql module functions but I cannot access the types (IConnection, IQuery, etc).
I can also see the parameter and return types from intellisense.

Example

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql'
...
getUser(username: string): User {
        mysql.createConnection({ host: "...", user: "...", password: "..." });
    }
```

But I'd like to make a method that returns a type defined in the mysql typings (IQuery for example)

Something like

```
getUser(username:string): IQuery{
}
```

Being a beginner in typescript coming from a c# background, I don't see what's going on here.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
I have tried prefixing he type without any success as well as importing through this format `import {IConnection} from 'mysql'`
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though ReSharper was my issue, I still haven't found how to omit the errors or fix them though.
I reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and it worked without Resharper, but when I did install it, I started having problems again.
Thanks for the help!
I'll edit this if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by prefixing the interface with `mysql`:

```
getUser(username:string): mysql.IQuery {

}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't show up or compile, maybe it's my IDE?

Comment: Have you actually installed the types? `npm install @types/mysql --save-dev`

Comment: Yes, I can see the types in my IDE, I just can't seem to be able to access them from outside the module. I also tried your command with no success.

Comment: I am able to use the interface with your exact same `tsconfig`. Can you post something reproducible?

Comment: It seems as though ReSharper was my issue, still haven't found how to fix it but it's out of subject.